# Use of date function in PHP to output a user-friendly date

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

I have a MySQL database column named DateAdded.
I'd like to echo this as a readable date/time.
Here is a simplified version of the code I currently have:

```
$result = mysql_query("
    SELECT ListItem, DateAdded
    FROM lists
    WHERE UserID = '" . $currentid . "' 
    ");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
    // Make the date look nicer
    $dateadded = date('d-m-Y',$row['DateAdded']);

    echo $row['ListItem'] . ",";
    echo $dateadded;
    echo "<br />";
    }
```

Is the use of the date function the best way to output a user-friendly date?

Thanks for taking a look,

Comment: Ideally dd-mm-yyyy (and nope, 2038+ doesn't matter)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't plan on outputting dates beyond 2038, you will be fine using `date()`.

Otherwise, use PHP's [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) which doesn't have that limitation, or [mySQL's date formatting functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) to format the date directly in the database.

However, you seem to be storing a timestamp in the database. Have you considered switching to  a `DATETIME` field?

Comment: The 2038 problem seems to fix itself. It works fine with larger timestamps on 64-bit. (Albeit it's a bit slow to calculate the weekends two billion years from now.)

Comment: @mario yeah, it's unlikely to become another Y2K bug. But I mean if he needs to work with dates > 2038 *right now* (not entirely out of the question e.g. in the finance industry, think credit calculators...)

Answer (score 1):

It is fine to use `date()` to show users.

Is there any reason you are not using the `DATE` type in MySQL?

Comment: Hi @alex, the type in MySQL is TIMESTAMP (so I can easily use CURRENT_TIMESTAMP to set it by default). If I just echo $row['DateAdded'] it displays 2011-02-09 14:47:45

Comment: @Jamie Sounds like you would need `strtotime()` it first then before passing to `date()`.

Answer (score 1):

I sometimes used MySQL's DATE_FORMAT().
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format